# How to sort Ruby Hash with dynamic keys

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash, key

I want to understand how I can sort ruby hashes with key and or their subkeys if need be. For examples:

**Example of hash with sub_hashs**

```
two_hash = {
  'a' => {'displayName' => "A", 'name' => "Apple", 'Association' => {'id' => '1', 'type' => 'B2'}},
  'c' => {'displayName' => "D", 'name' => "Banana", 'Association' => {'id' => '1', 'type' => 'B3'}},
  'b' => {'displayName' => "C", 'name' => "Orange", 'Association' => {'id' => '1', 'type' => 'B1'}},
  'd' => {'displayName' => "B", 'name' => "Kiwi", 'Association' => {'id' => '1', 'type' => 'B4'}}
}
```

**Currently I can sort it like this, calling and specify the key/subkey to sort by.**

```
puts (two_hash.sort_by {|h, k| k['displayName']})
puts (two_hash.sort_by {|h, k| k['Association']['type']})
```

I want to convert it to a proc and used it whenever I want given a subkey input.

I want it so I can just pass in a key or a subkey and it will sort for me. like so, is there a way to do this in Ruby?

```
sort_stuff_method(two_hash, ['displayname'])
sort_stuff_method(two_hash, ['Association']['type'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for,

```
def sort_stuff_method(input_hash, sort_key, sort_sub_key=nil)
  input_hash.sort_by{|h,k| sort_sub_key.nil? ? k[sort_key] : k[sort_key][sort_sub_key]}
end
```

and you can use it like this,

```
sort_stuff_method(input_hash, 'displayName')
sort_stuff_method(input_hash, 'Association', 'Type')
```

Comment: Thanks you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do that:

```
def sort_em(h, *nested_keys)
  h.sort_by { |k,v| nested_keys.reduce(v) { |g,k| g[k] } }
end

sort_em(two_hash, 'displayName')
  #=> [["a", {"displayName"=>"A", "name"=>"Apple",
  #           "Association"=>{"id"=>"1", "type"=>"B2"}}],
  #    ["d", {"displayName"=>"B", "name"=>"Kiwi",
  #           "Association"=>{"id"=>"1", "type"=>"B4"}}],
  #    ["b", {"displayName"=>"C", "name"=>"Orange",
  #           "Association"=>{"id"=>"1", "type"=>"B1"}}],
  #    ["c", {"displayName"=>"D", "name"=>"Banana",
  #           "Association"=>{"id"=>"1", "type"=>"B3"}}]] 

sort_em(two_hash, 'Association', 'type')
  #=> [["b", {"displayName"=>"C", "name"=>"Orange",
  #           "Association"=>{"id"=>"1", "type"=>"B1"}}],
  #    ["a", {"displayName"=>"A", "name"=>"Apple",
  #           "Association"=>{"id"=>"1", "type"=>"B2"}}],
  #    ["c", {"displayName"=>"D", "name"=>"Banana",
  #           "Association"=>{"id"=>"1", "type"=>"B3"}}],
  #    ["d", {"displayName"=>"B", "name"=>"Kiwi",
  #           "Association"=>{"id"=>"1", "type"=>"B4"}}]]
```

This of course works for any number of nested keys.